# Как оптимизировать php страниц?

Tags: php, оптимизация

Здравствуйте! Как оптимизировать php страниц?
У меня такой код который если юзер онлайн бла бла бла если оффлайн бла бла бла.

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (logged_in() === true) {
    include'include/on/index.php';
} else {
    include'include/off/index.php';
}
?>
```

Это нормально?

---

Или такой код лучше?

**index.php**

```
<?php
if (logged_in() === true) {
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
              <head>
              //Бла бла бла
              </head>
              <body>
              //Бла бла бла
              </body>
          </html>';
} else {
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
              <head>
              //Бла бла бла
              </head>
              <body>
              //Бла бла бла
              </body>
          </html>';
}
?>
```

Comment: начнем с того, что код вида `logged_in() === true` это уже плохо. Лучше писать просто `logged_in()`.

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя изначально не совсем правильный подход. Авторизованный пользователь, или нет - большая часть заголовков не измениться. Судя по всему, Вы пользуетесь функциональным подходом. Тогда это могло бы выглядеть так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
          <head>
             <?= 'Hello, '.(logged_in()) ? $user['username'] : 'Guest' ?>
             <?php foreach(getSeoMeta() as $k => $v) : ?>
                 <meta type="<?=$v['type']?>" ... />
             <?php endforeach ?>
          </head>
          <body>
          //Бла бла бла - header
             <?=$content?>
          //Bla-bla-footer
          </body>
      </html>
```

Я советовал бы пользоваться готовой моделью. к примеру MVC, MVVM. Информации по теме - море.

Comment: Спасибо но не понял код?! `<?=$content?>` это что такой код?

Comment: Это сокращенный синтаксис. Если написать полный код - получится <?php echo $content ?>

Comment: Ааааааа понял спасибо!!

Comment: @KYRAN, Конструкция `<?=` говорит что надо вывести данные. Между тегами нужна только выводимая информация.

Comment: @TheDoctor, Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 2):

Оба кода плохи.
Хотя если это просто упрощённый пример, то первый лучше, хотя ещё лучше - отделять вид от остального.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score -1):

Проверку логично разместить в Контроллере. И скорее всего это будет примерно так: если не залогинен, то разговор короткий, а если залогинен, то надо добыть данные и только потом обратиться к Представлению.

```
if (!$auth->is_logged_in()) {
  $view->render('not_athorized_please_login.tpl');
  exit();
}

$user = $auth->get_user();
$data = $model->fetch_some_data();
// ... ... ...
$view->render('page.tpl', ['user => $user, 'data' => $data]);
```

Comment: Мы понятия не имеем о его логике приложения, так что...

Comment: Так что что? Мы понятия не имеем о тайном смысле вашего многоточия, например. Это повод чтобы не давать советов? П.М.С.М. — нет. Пусть рассмотрит разные варианты. Я стараюсь донести мысль, что варианты "залогинен" и "не залогинен" несимметричны. И что в Представлении лучше держать поменьше логики.